# convert an image from base64 to normal image fromat in salesforce integration

Tags: rest-api, integration

i am working on integration on Rest API.
i want to convert an image from base 64 to normal format in salesforce 
How can i do it.

i am giving my code here.
if there is any isues, suggest to me.

### code:

```
//https://ashdummytest-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/services/apexrest/WebPage

@RestResource(urlMapping = '/WebPage/*')
global class WebPageRest {
    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        Map < String, String > param = req.params;
        System.debug('----param-----' + param);
        String respStr = 'Welcome Get ';
        System.debug('--hub.verify_token--' + param.get('hub.verify_token'));
        String challange;
        if (param.get('hub.challenge') != null) {
            respStr = param.get('hub.challenge');
        } else if (param.get('code') != null) {
            respStr = param.get('code');
        }
        res.statuscode = 200;
        res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.responsebody = Blob.valueof(respStr);
        System.debug('----res.responsebody-----' + res.responsebody);
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost() {

        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        Map < String, String > param = req.params;
        String respStr = 'Welcome Post Integration';
        System.debug('---- post param-----' + param);
        String jsonStr = req.requestBody.toString();
        System.debug('----req.reqbody-----' + jsonStr);
        res.statuscode = 200;
        res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.responsebody = Blob.valueof(respStr);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you wanting to do with said image? Store as blob somewhere or render in UI?

Comment: i want to store as blob somewhere

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the relevance of the code you've posted, but to store an image as a document or attachment, you must convert the Base64 string to a Blob.

I've illustrated doing this with this code:

```
string imageUrl = 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(imageUrl);
request.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

// encode to get base64 (this is just to illustrate the point)
String base64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(response.getBodyAsBlob());

// now decode to get image/blob (again to illustrate the point)
Blob image = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64);

// save as Document
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Name = 'googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
doc.Body = image;
doc.ContentType = 'image/png';
doc.FolderId = '00524000001IW6u';
insert doc;
```

Comment: i am getting my response like this.